# How to initialize struct members at compile time, depending on the value of previously defined entries in an array

Tags: c, struct, initialization, embedded

Suppose I have a structure used for describing values stored inside a virtual memory map:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t u16ID;
    uint16_t u16Offset;
    uint8_t u8Size;
} MemMap_t;

const MemMap_t memoryMap[3] =
{
    {
        .u16ID = 0,
        .u16Offset = 0,
        .u8Size = 3
    },
    {
        .u16ID = 1,
        .u16Offset = 3,
        .u8Size = 2
    },
    {
        .u16ID = 2,
        .u16Offset = 5,
        .u8Size = 3
    }
};
```

- Each entry contains an offset for addressing the memory location and the size of the value it contains
- The offset of each following value is dependent on the offset and size of the values before it

In this example I set all offsets manually.

The reason why I implemented it that way is that it allows me to change the layout of the entire memory map later on,
the structure still making it possible to look up the offset and size of an entry with a certain ID.

The problem with this is that setting the offsets manually is going to get unwieldy quite quickly once the map becomes bigger
and changing the size of an entry at the beginning would require manually changing all offsets of the entries after that one.

I came up with some ways to just calculate the offsets at runtime, but as the target system this will run on is a very RAM constrained embedded system, I really want to keep the entire map as a constant.

Is there an elegant way to calculate the offsets of the map entries at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

After some experiments, found something that may work for large number of attributes. Posting as new answer, as my previous answer took very different approach.

Consider create a proxy structure that describe the object described by MamMap_t, using series of char[] objects.

```
static struct MemMap_v {
    char t0[3] ;
    char t1[2] ;
    char t2[3] ;
    char t3[10] ;
} vv ;

const MemMap_t memoryMap[3] =
{
    {
        .u16ID = 0,
        .u16Offset = vv.t0 - vv.t0,
        .u8Size = sizeof(vv.t0)
    },
    {
        .u16ID = 1,
        .u16Offset = vv.t1 - vv.t0,
        .u8Size = sizeof(vv.t1)
    },
    {
        .u16ID = 2,
        .u16Offset = vv.t2 - vv.t0,
        .u8Size = sizeof(vv.t2)
    }
};
```

Comment: That's quite a creative solution.
The entry definition being split into two separate code locations makes maintainability a bit iffy
so I'm still leaning with an external code generator so that the layout of the map is obvious at a glance and easy to change
but this works and isn't something I even thought of, so thank you.

Comment: What about possible padding bytes in the `MemMap_v` structure?

Comment: Note: you could avoid the `vv.t2 - vv.t0` substration(s) by using the `offsetof()` macro.

Comment: @exnihilo there is no information in the question about target platform alignment. If needed, the `packed` attribute can be used to compact the items. On x86_64, the items are packed by default.

Comment: @wildplasser good point. I was not expecting offsetof to work as const expression.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an elegant way to calculate the offsets of the map entries at compile time?

Yes: write yourself a code generator that accepts input data describing the memory map and outputs C source for the initializer or for the whole declaration.  Have the appropriate source file `#include` that.  Structure this program so that the form of its input data is convenient for you to maintain.

If the number of map entries were bounded by a (very) small number, and if their IDs were certain to be consecutive and to correspond to their indices in the `memoryMap` array, then I feel pretty confident that it would be possible to write a set of preprocessor macros that did the job without a separate program.  Such a preprocessor-based solution would be messy, and difficult to debug and maintain.  I do not recommend this alternative.

Comment: The IDs won't necessarily correspond to the indices in the actual code or be consecutive, so any pre-processor based solution based on this won't work.
I didn't have to use a code generator for anything up to now, but it does seem to be the most elegant and easily maintainable solution for this problem.
I will look into this further, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: not possible to calculate values at compile time, given data structure.

Alternative:

Consider using symbolic constants for the sizes. E_0, E_1, E_2, ..., then you can calculate the offset at compile time (E_0, E_0+E_1, E_0+E_1+E_2). Not very elegant, and does not scale well for large number of items, but will meet the requirements.

Second alternative will be to create a function that will return the pointer to memoryMap. The function can initialize the offset on the first call. The program will call getMemoryMap instead of memoryMap.

```
static MemMap_t memoryMap[3] =
{
    ...
}

const MemMap_t *getMemoryMap() {
    MemMap_t *p = memoryMap ;
    static bool offsetDone ;
    if ( !offsetDone ) {
        offsetDone = true ;
        for (int i=1; i<sizeof(memoryMap)/sizeof(memoryMap[0]) ; i++ ) {
            p[i].u16Offset  = p[i-1].u16Offset + p[i-1].u8Size ;
    } ;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Symbolic constants used like that would get quite messy unfortunately as the actual code will contain around 50 entries inside the map.

The function example works, but unfortunately does not allow the map to remain const.

I already feared it would not be possible to do this at compile time but I've seen some people do crazy things using the
pre-processor so I wanted to ask anyway.

If nothing else comes up I will probably look into the possibility of piping the code through something like awk to do the job before
compilation.